# CSS Solution For Ignoring Transform Of Parent Div

Tags: css, transform

I have a layout like this:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
  <h1>Sticky text</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }

.wrapper {
  width: 1024px;
  display: block;
}

.child {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-80px);
-ms-transform: translateY(-80px);
 transform: translateY(-80px);
 transition: transform .5s ease;
 z-index: 31;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 100%;
}
```

Since parent has `transform` of 0 my child wont stay fixed. However if i remove parent `transform` the child get's sticked just fine. is there any way around  this? without deleting the `transform` of the parent? Maybe flex?

Comment: @AndyHoffman AKA stay fixed to the parent upon scrolling

Comment: Usually people create a reverse transform to "cancel" the parent's one. However, I recommend using a pseudo element to the parent with your desired effect so that other children will not be affected - your code isn't clear and your HTML has an error (must close class "")

Comment: @Aziz even if i wrap the wrapper in another div and sit it's transform to none. the child will still be effected by the parent.

Comment: Let me simplify: `parent > transformed child + normal child` is that clear? siblings do not affect each other's transform. Also can you explain what you are trying to achieve with this exactly?

Comment: @Aziz Check this out: http://codepen.io/ilanus/pen/oLWPBB you will notice a little border on top of the composition. remove the css properties of the push class the the div get's sticked to the bottom just fine. Why?